# How can I implode() a multidimensional array into a string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which has multiple arrays inside of like. Here is how it looks like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => s1
        [1] => s2
        [2] => s5
        [3] => s1
        [4] => s25
        [5] => s1
        [6] => s6
        [7] => s6
        [8] => s1
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => a2
        [1] => a1
        [2] => a4
    )
    [3] =>  Array ( )
    [4] =>  Array ( )
)
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can turn these multiple arrays into 1 string where is has values from all arrays split with commas `$values = "s1,s2,s5.."`

I used `impode()` before but with this type of array, it's not functioning. Another problem in this is empty arrays which i believe can be removed with `array_filter()`.

```
$destination_array = array_filter($tags_list);
$destination_array = implode(",", $tags_list);
print_r($destination_array);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a two dimensional array here. And neither [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) work with multidimensional arrays.

This means you filter all empty values out of the first dimension and also try to implode the first dimension:

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => s1
            [1] => s2
            [2] => s5
            [3] => s1
            [4] => s25
            [5] => s1
            [6] => s6
            [7] => s6
            [8] => s1
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => a2
            [1] => a1
            [2] => a4
        )
        [3] =>  Array ( )
        [4] =>  Array ( )
         ↑ Filter first dimension and implode it
    )
```

So obviously what you have to do is, you have to filter **each subArray**. Then implode each subArray and implode all strings together again.

How can we do this? Just use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

With `array_map()` you go through each subArray and first filter all empty values out with `array_filter()`. Then you `implode()` each subArray to a string. After this you will end up with an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => s1,s2,s5,s1,s25,s1,s6,s6,s1
    [2] => a2,a1,a4
)
```

And then you have to implode it again to get 1 string out of it.

Code:

```
echo implode(",", array_filter(array_map(function($v){
         return implode(",", array_filter($v));
     }, $array)));
```

output:

```
s1,s2,s5,s1,s25,s1,s6,s6,s1,a2,a1,a4
```

Comment: One more thing @Rizier123 with your answer how can i calculate the most common array value? In this case it would result in `s1`.

Comment: @aqq You would merge the arrays together with `array_map("array_merge", $array)` and then use `array_count_values()` to get the occurrence of each element, sort it, and then get the one value with the most occurrences

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be achieved a number of ways (beyond Rizier's function approach which is good and clean):

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nfEjR)

Method #1: the boring / loopy / fast way

```
$array = [
    ['s1','s2','s5','s1','s25','s1','s6','s6','s1'],
    2 => ['a2','a1','a4'],
    [],
    []
];
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    if ($subarray) {
        $result[] = implode(',', $subarray);
    }
}
echo implode(',', $result);
```

Method #2: the handy "leafnode" grabber

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($v) {
        static $first;
        echo $first . $v;
        $first = ',';
    }
);
```

Method #3: the slower, unorthodox regex ways:

```
echo implode(
         ',',
         preg_match_all(
             '/[a-z]\d+/',
             json_encode($array),
             $out
         )
         ? $out[0]
         : []
     );
```

And

```
echo implode(
         ',',
         preg_split(
             '/\W+/',
             json_encode(array_values($array)),
             0,
             PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
         )
     );
```

Output (from each of the above:

```
s1,s2,s5,s1,s25,s1,s6,s6,s1,a2,a1,a4
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

```
$str='';
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        $str.=implode(',',$v);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not put commas between ALL values.